# How to fix C++ compiler is not able to compile github repo in R

Tags: r, github

I use Rtools c++ compiler to compile a github repo via cmake, and error says that C++ compiler Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe is not able to compile a simple test program.

devtools::install_github("tractatus/wholebrain", args='--no-multiarch')
.....
.....

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
  The C++ compiler

```
"C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Windows/Temp/RtmpuqHViQ/R.INSTALL5c036fc6900/ROpenCVLite/src/opencv-4.0.1/build64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"C:/Rtools/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_96862/fast"
/Rtools/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_96862.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_96862.dir/build
make: /bin/sh: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_96862/fast] Error 127
```

and I try to install cmake in another version and rtools, but it seemly not work. So, what's the problem for this?

Comment: It looks like your make file is trying to run `/bin/sh`.  Rtools contains `sh.exe`, but it wouldn't be stored in `\bin` on Windows.

Comment: @user2554330 The error report seemly like to be this，but Rtools installation is just like that. Moreover, There’s also a error report that Rtools\bin should not be added to my path in the early time.